# Converting a Symbol into a String

Tags: dart

Is there a way to covert a Symbol into a String?

For instance, a VariableMirror returns Symbols instead of Strings. Is there a way to convert a Symbol into a String, so I can print all the variable names of a class?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use [MirrorSystem.getName()](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-mirrors.MirrorSystem#id_getName):

```dart
import 'dart:mirrors';

void main() {
  var sym = new Symbol('test');
  print(MirrorSystem.getName(sym));
}
```

This outputs:

```
test
```

Comment: Awesome but unstable and adds additional megabytes to the bundle for html dart. And mirrors is not supported for flutter for now ((

Answer (score 2):

It turns out there is an easy solution

```dart
print(MirrorSystem.getName(symbol));
```

prints

> somename

see also: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=17471

**EDIT**

*An interesting comment to the issue linked above from @lrn*

> It is "difficult to use" on purpose. Symbols can be minified by dart2js, and looking up their original name is only done through the mirror system. This allows dart2js to know whether the feature is used at all, and not include a translation table if it isn't necessary.
>   In general, I recommend coding in a way that doesn't need to convert symbols to strings, if at all possible. Treat them as opaque tokens, and only compare them to other tokens.

The [smoke package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/smoke) provides a service for this that gets translated to code by its transformer in a way that also works in minified JavaScript. `symbolToName()` and `nameToSymbol()`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm stack on this question as well.
I can't use 'dart:mirrors' in my package, so using the below:

```
String s = new Symbol('hi').toString();
s = s.substring(8,pn.length-2);
```

Looks terrible but it gets the job sort of done. Maybe there is a performance issue though.

## Edit:

#### `Chance is great things breaks in minified JS. Stongly discouraged!` by Günter Zöchbauer

Did not think about this, thanks.
Even if it worked now, there are chances of breakage in the future, so I guess 'toString()' better be avoided.

Confirmed:

```
Warning: 'hi=' is used reflectively but not in MirrorsUsed. This will break minified code.index.bootstrap.initialize.dart.js:7612 
Warning: 'hi' is used reflectively but not in MirrorsUsed. This will break minified code`
```

Comment: Chance is great things breaks in minified JS.  Stongly discouraged!

Comment: As far as I know the whole purpose of `Symbol` instead of just `String` was to prevent it to break when minification mangles identifier names.

Comment: @ Günter Zöchbauer Hmm, thanks. That probably means Mirrors has an internal symbol to string conversion table presumably created at compile time or the method name before minification can be computed from the name after minification. I will dig into Mirrors now...

Comment: I don't know details. I guess `dart2js` treats them differently so that the relation doesn't break.

Answer (score 0):

Some example code:

```
// Listen for App changes so we can do some things.
app.changes.listen((List<ChangeRecord> records) {
  PropertyChangeRecord record = records[0] as PropertyChangeRecord;
  String changedValue = MirrorSystem.getName(record.name);

  if (changedValue == "pageTitle") {
    print("$changedValue changed!");
  }
}
```