# Is it possible to test whether a Dart List is growable?

Tags: dart

Given a `List`, is it possible to test whether the list is growable?

Trying to set the `length` and catching an `UnsupportedError` seems like a solution (though it isn't clear what would happen if you just set the length to the same value). Any better solution?

Comment: I'm surprised to see that there do not appear to be any bugs (opened or closed) requesting a bool property on List to check this.

Comment: I just added it now :) https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=17469

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to detect if a list is growable (short of using reflection to find the implementation type, which is brittle, won't work the same way in dart2js, and increases code size).

The only valid use-case we encountered was to have checks/asserts when a library returns a list. In all other cases a function/library tried to modify an argument without knowing if it was allowed to do that.

If a function/library can work destructively it should require a boolean (or similar) so that the callers can decide if their argument can be changed. The callee should never silently modify its inputs unless it is obvious (for example `fillFoo(list)`) or an argument tells it so (for instance `computeSquares(list, inPlace: true)`).

http://dartbug.com/13926 is still open, but I expect it to be closed tomorrow with status "NotPlanned".

Comment: Florian, thank you for the background and the explanation. What you suggest makes sense as a convention.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using reflection (not straight-forward either).
I guess this isn't any better than catching the exception.

```dart
print(MirrorSystem.getName(reflect(new List.from([0,1,2], growable: true))
    .type.simpleName) == ('_GrowableList'));
```

**EDIT**
It is discouraged to use the name of a symbol - see [Converting a Symbol into a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16058505)